# Two Blinkers, A Pair of Boats, etc

Tags: word, knowledge, visual, cellular-automata

<sub>This puzzle is part of the [Monthly Topic Challenge #8: Cellular Automata](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7452/monthly-topic-challenge-8-cellular-automata).</sub>

---

Find four capital letters that can replace the X's (and explain why).

[image: Puzzle]

Comment: two blocks leaning left / two blocks leaning left / my muscles, my muscles / involuntarily flex

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think the answers are as follows

> **L.** Two blocks leaning left
>  **I.** Four Blinkers
>  **F.** Honey Farm
>  **E.** Devil laughing on his side?

Notice how it spells

> **LIFE**

That's because

> Each of the clues is describing a configuration in [Conway's Game of Life](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%27s_Game_of_Life). The clues represent the configuration that the game settles down to if we begin with a configuration described by the corresponding number or letter.

For example

> If we begin with "2" given as follows,
>  [image]
>  after several generations, it settles down to become a "pair of boats"
>  [image]

Another example

> If we begin with "E"
>  [image]
>  Then, after several generations, it settles down to become this
>  [image]
>  which looks like the devil on his side and the mouth is a blinker (suggesting laughing).

Try it for yourself

> I've been using this site: https://playgameoflife.com/

Title Explanation (thanks to Amoz for drawing my attention)

> "Two Blinkers, A Pair of Boats" correspond to the numbers **4** and **2** and **42** is The Answer  to the Ultimate Question of *Life*, the Universe and Everything in [The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Hitchhiker%27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy_(novel))

Comment: Great! Bonus explain the title.

Comment: @Amoz, good point, I totally overlooked this. Very nice puzzle!

Comment: What's the significance of the position of each clue in the graphic in the question?

Comment: @RosieF This is probably incorrect, but rot13(Vg frrzf gb ercerfrag gur tevq va gur Tnzr bs Yvsr. Ubjrire, vs lbh chg gung cnegvphyne flfgrz vagb gur Tnzr bs Yvsr, vg qvrf bhg nsgre n srj gheaf.)

Comment: @RosieF I don't know if there is any particular significance to the ordering apart from the first two (see title) and the last four. There are only certain letters and numbers that will yield distinct patterns so possibly a random ordering between those available?

Comment: @RosieF rot13(Gur pyhrf ner neovgenel ohg gur neenatrzrag vf n 13 cvkry qvtvgny qvfcynl gb thvqr ubj gb funcr lbhe punenpgref.)